# Check to specific VC in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to check specific VC if app is running in foreground. My root view controller class is `SWRevealViewController`. After that I have a `TabBarController` and under it there is `NavigationController` and `ViewController` under it.

My heirachy is,

> SWRevealViewController --> TabBar Controller --> Navigation Controller --> MessageVC --> ChatVC

I want to check in app delegate if app is on **ChatVC** or not if running on foreground.I have tried this code,

```
    let tabBar:UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

    let navInTab:UINavigationController = tabBar.viewControllers?[1] as! UINavigationController

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Dashboard", bundle: nil)
    let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatDetailViewController") as? ChatDetailViewController

    if destinationViewController?.restorationIdentifier == "ChatDetailViewController"
    {
        print("Yes")
    }
    else
    {
        print("No")
    }
```

But app crashes with this error,

> Could not cast value of type 'SWRevealViewController' (0x100dc4b20) to 'UITabBarController' (0x211b289f0).

How i can check if app is on ChatVC or not?

**Screenshot of storyboard :**

[image]

Comment: check window?.visibleViewController

Comment: Instead of TabBar NavigationController, you need to check  in `SWRevealViewController`  NavigationController.

Comment: How i can check that? @dahiya_boy

Comment: I have set this , let vc = UIStoryboard().loadSWRevealController()
        appDeleg.window?.rootViewController = vc
        appDeleg.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() . in DidFinish Delegate . @KrishnaDattShukla

Answer (score 0):

I never used `SWRevealViewController` but you can try this.

---

1. As you said in your first line *"SWRevealViewController is the RooVC"* and you are converting the `SWRevealViewController` to `UITabBarController` (check below line of your code). This is your crash reason.

   ```
   let tabBar:UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
   ```
2. Now you need to change, `UITabBarController` to `SWRevealViewController`

   ```
   let rootVC = self.window?.rootViewController as! SWRevealViewController
   ```
3. Now get all ViewControllers

   ```
   if let navController = rootVC.navigationController { // for safety check

       for controller in navController.viewControllers {
           if controller is ChatVC {
               print("Chat VC is available")
               break
           }
       }
   }
   ```

---

For safe coding and keeping swift optional binding in mind, you can do code like below,

> Updated answer

```
    var haveChatVC = false
    if let rootVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? SWRevealViewController,
        let tabbar = rootVC.frontViewController as? UITabBarController {

        if let requiredNC = tabbar.viewControllers?[1] as? UINavigationController {
            for vc in requiredNC.viewControllers {
                if vc is ChatVC {
                    // ...
                    haveChatVC = true
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        else {
           print("Navigation controller not found.")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Unable to get root controller or navigation controller")
    }


    if haveChatVC {
        // do task here when chat vc available
    }
    else {
        // do task here when chat vc not available
    }
```

---

**Note:** This is only pseudo code.

Comment: Bro i have tried ur code it isn't coming inside the for loop. I think its due to we have to first get the tab bar controller after rootVC and than check VC under it , as u can see my flow heriachy in question. @dahiya_boy

Comment: Try to print `navController.viewControllers` . And let me know its output.

Comment: Unable to get root controller or navigation controller . @dahiya_boy

Comment: What is the output of `print(self.window?.rootViewController)` ??

Comment: Optional(<SWRevealViewController: 0x13e835e00>) . it printing this . @dahiya_boy

Comment: Bro My heriachy is SWRevealViewController --> TabBar Controller --> Nav Controller --> MessageVC --> ChatVC . @dahiya_boy

Comment: @Hamza NP, I need some debug information. After doing some google I found that you need to work on `rootVC.frontViewController` instead of `rootVC. navigationController`. According to your heirarchy `rootVC.frontViewController` should be `UITabBarController`. Can you check and confirm me once. If it is true then change `let navController = rootVC.navigationController` to `let tabBar = rootVC.frontViewController as? UITabBarController`

Comment: @Hamza **NOTE :** Make sure you are debugging in `applicationWillEnterForeground` and after launch your app push to ChatVC and then goto background and then open the app again. In this case  `applicationWillEnterForeground` will called.

Comment: Now it comes inside the for loop but condition does not match with Chat VC. I think first we have to check MessageVC in for loop and Chat VC is under MessageVC. @dahiya_boy

Comment: Bro its again showing this, "Unable to get root controller or navigation controller" . @dahiya_boy

Comment: @Hamza ..  check updated answer, comment for-loop and `print(tabbar.viewControllers)`

Comment: Its showing this, Optional([<UINavigationController: 0x10385ca00>, <UINavigationController: 0x103826a00>, <UINavigationController: 0x103827000>]) . @dahiya_boy

Comment: On my tab 2 index i have MessageVC and under it their is ChatVC. @dahiya_boy

Answer (score 0):

I have an extension for it

```
extension UIApplication {

class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        let moreNavigationController = tab.moreNavigationController
        if let top = moreNavigationController.topViewController, top.view.window != nil {
            return topViewController(base: top)
        } else if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(base: presented)
    }
    return base
}
```

}

USAGE:

```
    if UIApplication.topViewController is YourViewController {
```

// do smth
}

Comment: I have tried this, it doesn't worked for me because my root view controller is SWRevealViewController . @Alexandr Kolesnik

Comment: You can try some workaround, create ViewController with flag, inherit all controllers from ViewController, change flag in viewDidLoad, then check flag